# Submit not submitting form but moving cursor to input field

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm out of options and a bit frustrated. I'm not that familiar with HTML but I have got two forms one where a button of the type="submit" sends my view model to the server side controller and this here where it does not do it. In this form, if I click the submit button the cursor gets moved to the Surcharges[i].Price input field in my table instead. The only difference between the two forms is that this form here has input fields in the table whereas the other has select fields.

```html
<form autocomplete="off" asp-controller="PriceList" asp-action="UpdateSurchargeFixPrices" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
                <h4 class="text-center">@localizer["PriceListEdit"]</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <input hidden value="@Model.BackTo" asp-for="BackTo" />
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table-secondary">
                            <th>@localizer["Bezeichnung"]</th>
                            <th>@localizer["Gruppe"]</th>
                            <th>@localizer["Code"]</th>
                            <th>@localizer["Maximaler Wert in"] @Model.Currency</th>
                            <th>@localizer["Preis in"] @Model.Currency</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (Model.Surcharges != null)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Surcharges.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input hidden value="@Model.Surcharges[i].Id" asp-for="Surcharges[i].Id" /><input value="@Model.Surcharges[i].Description" asp-for="Surcharges[i].Description" /></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input value="@Model.Surcharges[i].Group" asp-for="Surcharges[i].Group" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input value="@Model.Surcharges[i].Code" asp-for="Surcharges[i].Code" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input value="@Model.Surcharges[i].MaxValue" asp-for="Surcharges[i].MaxValue" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input value="@Model.Surcharges[i].Price" asp-for="Surcharges[i].Price" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="PriceList" asp-action="BackTo" asp-route-backTo="@Model.BackTo">@localizer["zurück"]</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="PriceList" asp-action="NewSurchargeFixPrice">@localizer["neuer Aufschlag"]</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@localizer["speichern"]</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This sounds like you have enabled client side validation by including a partial file named __ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml_ and that your form is not valid. However, you have not included any validation message helpers, so you are not seeing any validation errors. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml but the form validation part was useful I change the input field to < input formnovalidate="formnovalidate".../> and now I can reach the breakpoint in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I change the input field to

```
< input formnovalidate="formnovalidate".../>
```

and now I can reach the breakpoint in my controller.